# Extract .tar.gz Contents into Folder using SharpZipLib - C#

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I'm using `SharpZipLib` to extract a .tar.gz file using this code:

```
new FastZip().ExtractZip(source, destination, null);
```

But the program will give the error below:

> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: 'Cannot find central
>   directory'

I can extract that file using third party apps like WinRAR. so the file is correct but I can not find the problem extracting it with `SharpZipLib`.

If there is another way that `SharpZipLib`, it would be perfect also.